# Indexeddb cursor wait for response?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, indexeddb

I have an application which contains a indexeddb database. It saves info for a while. If this info was not passed to the server, for example due to a network error, the "synced" is set to false. Now I want to create a function that is able to upload the items with status: "synced:false" to the server.

The idea is to iterate through the db and everytime there is an entry with false, upload it to the server and on succes update the value in the local (indexeddb) db.

The problem I'm having is that I can't see how I can let the cursor operation wait for the response of the server (REST API) and then do actions accordingly (update local value "synced:false" -> "synced:true". The update to the server goes well.

Here is a working Stackblitz that shows the full code on the Homepage:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-thu3eg

Output is in the console.
This is an example with the actual problem.

```
  update() {
    var callstring: string;
    let nowTime = new Date().toISOString();
    let nowTimes = dateFns.format(nowTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    const dbPromise = openDb('testdb', 1);
    dbPromise.then(async db => {
      const tx = db.transaction('scans', 'readwrite');
      tx.objectStore('scans').iterateCursor(async cursor => {
        if (!cursor) return;
        if (cursor.value.synced == 'false') {
          console.log(cursor.value);

          await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
              .map(res => res.json())
              .subscribe(res => {
                console.log('response : ', res.id);
                resolve(res)
                return callstring = res.id;
              }, error => {
                reject(error)
              });
          });

          if (callstring == '1') {
            console.log('do something : ', callstring);
            cursor.value.synced = 'true';
            cursor.value.time = nowTimes;
            cursor.update(cursor.value);
          } else {
            console.log('sorry too late');
          }
        }
        await cursor.continue();
      });
      await tx.complete.then(() => console.log('done cursoring'));

    }).then(() => {
      this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: "DB updated",
        duration: 2000,
        position: 'top',
        cssClass: "toast-mess"
      }).present();
    });
  }
```

So if callstring = 1 then it should update the "false" value to "true" in the indexeddb.

How can I solve this ?
Thanks

Comment: What indexeddb wrapper are you using?

Comment: the one from Jake Archibald

Comment: Avoid calling and awaiting non-indexeddb async calls while indexeddb operations are running, things will not always work as expected

Comment: This `return callstring = res.id;` does not make much sense. You don't need the `return` there. Either just do the assignment in the callback, or move it outside and resolve the promise with `res.id`. But it should set callstring before the `if` so it should not be a porblem. Also, awaiting on `cursor.continue()` is also pointless because of the way `iterateCursor` works. After continue is called, the `async cursor=>...` will be called with a cursor ready to use for the next iteration. So can you tell what is not working exactly?

Comment: I will rework the code

Comment: Taking error you posted in your answer into account, @Josh is probably right. IndexedDB transactions autocommit, so they are alive as long as new requests keep coming. When you make an HTTP request while a transaction is open, it just finishes before you get a response.